# Validating XML against XSD Node.js

Tags: node.js, xsd-validation

I'm trying to validate a XML against a XSD schema using node `libxmljs` module,

I'm getting this error

```
return this._validate(xsd);
                ^

Error: Invalid XSD schema
```

I've been reading a lot and it seems that this module doesn't accept schemas that imports other schemas. The schema I'm using is local and also the import schemas, I'm reading the file using the `fs` module like this:

```
var json = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(jsonLocal, 'utf-8'));
var xsd2 = fs.readFileSync(xsdLocal, 'utf-8');

var xml = parser(json, true);

var xsdDoc = libxml.parseXml(xsd2);
var xmlDoc = libxml.parseXml(xml);

xmlDoc.validate(xsdDoc);
```

but I get the error described at the beginning.

Does anyone know if what I'm trying to do is possible with this module? or maybe any other module that can do the job?

here's the schema that I'm using: ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/pub/jats/publishing/1.1/xsd/JATS-Publishing-1-1-MathML3-XSD.zip